# Is variable in C something like label in Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

Simple question: Is a variable in C something like a label in Assembly?

Or is a label in Assembly is like a pointer in C? Would anyone like to describe differences and similarities to me?

Comment: No, variables are often locals, inside the local call stack frame.

Comment: A label on data in assembly would be more like a global or static variable in C, but not a local variable. It would not be like a pointer in C, which is the name of a location that has a pointer (or address).

Comment: @scy7he in assembly language, if you have a label on a data item, the data item's value can change at run time.

Comment: Declaring a variable does two things: 1) is allocates space in some way 2) it introduces a name for it. So it is more or less comparable to `... foo BYTE 'A'` in (pseudo) assembler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Label in assembly marks a memory location. It would be equivalent to (address of) static variable in C, or an exported global variable in case you export the label.

C also has local variables, which are generally stored in stack frame of a function call. This is also commonly done in assembly, by adjusting stack pointer in the function to make room (and using register like x86 *BP* to conveniently access them, usually). With optimizations enables, local variables might also be stored in registers, which is also common in assembly.

Label itself in assembly means address of memory location, there are no "variables" as such in assembly, you get the value by using the address marked by the label. Static variable in C means the variable (value), there is no direct way to create label like in assembly, you need to get address with `&`. But this is just syntactic difference really.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  A global variable in C has a fixed location in memory and for sake of argument a label in assembly language also has a fixed location.  When you access a global variable in C the resulting assembly is not necessarily a label that is accessed by the assembly but it has the same result.  In assembly if you wanted to have some static/global location of memory to store an item you generally will use a label plus an offset to access that item.  Granted an optimizer may remove the actual memory accesses and that memory location may not be touched or not as much, but that is okay.

For local static variables from the backends perspective they are the same, a static location that you accesses.  At a low level they cannot be distinguished from a global.

For stack variables (local non-static) a lot of times compilers use a stack frame which has the effect of for the duration of the function individual variables are at a known offset in the stack frame...a static place.  Like the global labels are not used just a compiler computed offset, but this offset is not based on some label but based on a stack frame pointer.  here again an optimizer may remove a local variable and its stack location completely if it feels there is no need to actually write it to ram.  either there are enough registers to hold it for the duration, or its actual use can be implemented as an immediate or the math is computed compile time and the intermediate variables are removed, etc.

So a label is loosely similar to a variable if you were hand coding assembly language and using global variables.  Associating a label and a function name is a lot more realistic as the compiler will actually generate a label for each function (not optimized out).